# Expo: ios App Store Build Timeout due to expo-updates

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-updates

I'm currently working on building an ios app using expo sdk48, but have noticed that my production builds (using `eas build --profile production --platform ios`) continue to timeout in fastlane once they reach the following step:

`Executing expo-updates Pods/EXUpdates » [CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates`

This seems strange because when I build my app for internal distribution the build does not get stuck, but fastlane does output the following warning:

`Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')`

For reference, here is my eas.json and app.json configuration

**eas.json**

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.1.0",
    "appVersionSource": "remote"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "channel": "preview",
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "channel": "production",
      "autoIncrement": true,
      "ios": {
        "image": "latest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
   ...,
   "updates": {
     "enable": true,
     "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
     "url": "https://u.expo.dev/<my-project-id>"
   },
   "plugins": {
     ["expo-updates", {"username": "<my-account-username>"}]
   }
  }  
}
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before, or can shed some light on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to discern why this is the case, but the solution was to change the resource used in expo build from `m1-medium` to `intel-medium`.

My eas.json looks like this:

```
{
  ...,
  "build": {
    ...,
    "production": {
      ...,
      "ios": {
        "image": "latest",
        "resourceClass": "intel-medium"
      }
    }
  }
}
```